# Are unplaced genomic scaffolds unique compared to actual chromosomes?

Tags: scaffold, dna-sequence, blat

I used UCSC blat to search for a horse genomic sequence.  Three results were returned, two were unplaced scaffolds, and the other was chr1.  All had 100% identity to my query (gagttcctagacaccaaatacaacgtgggaatacacaacctactggcctatgtgaaacacctgaaaggccagaatgaggaagccctgaagagcttgagagaagctgaagacttaatccaggaagaacatggtgaccaatcaggcat).
My question is, are there 3 copies of this gene in the horse, or can the scaffolds belong to chr1?  For what its worth, there is only one copy of the gene in mouse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about dna encoding and has nothing whatsoever to do with IT

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be all 3 results are unique places in the genome.  Unplaced scaffolds are sequences in the genome that are being worked on, but have not been added to the reference genome.